# Count events over a period of time and yield the sum once every second in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is it possible to count events over a period of time and yield the sum once every second in RxJS? I have a continuous never ending stream of events. Every 1 second I would like to get the total number of events over the last 5 minute window. The idea is to use this to populate a realtime graph.

I know how to do this the traditional way but would really like to understand how it's done with reactive programming.

Comment: I don't know what RxJs is, but if you want to really output sum for the last 5 minutes, you will need a buffer with timestamps, so that you can properly drop values older than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd tackle it.

Create one observable that just counts the number of events received and emits this as a running total (via `scan`).
Create a second observable which is just the running total delayed by 5 minutes.
Create a third observable which just subtracts the delayed observable from the first observable. This will yield the running total of events that are younger than 5 minutes.
Create a final observable that samples this third observable once per second.

```
const totalLast5Minutes = eventSource.publish(events => {
    const runningTotal = events
        .scan((e, total) => total + 1, 0)
        .startWith(0);
    const totalDelayed5Minutes = runningTotal
        .delay(5000 * 60)
        .startWith(0);
    return Rx.Observable
        .combineLatest(total, totalDelayed5Minutes, (t, td) => t - td);
});

// only sample the value once per second
Rx.Observable
    .interval(1000)
    .withLatestFrom(totalLast5Minutes, (interval, total) => total)
    .subscribe(total => console.log(`total=${total}`));
```

Comment: Thank you Brandon, works like a charm. I've also tried using a buffer with a timeshift parameter which gives the same result but has a few drawbacks. Your solution can even be primed with inital data from database storage (so there is no delay before the running value is "correct"). You saved me a few hours and a headache :).

Comment: so simple yet so powerful. Curious how many lines of vanilla procedural code it would require to accomplish this

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way of doing it that I think may be a little simpler. You can use windowWithTime - see [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html) and [RxJS doc](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/windowwithtime.md). You can create windows that overlap, so you can have a 5 minute window of events, followed by another 5 minute window of events that started one second later, and another one second after that, etc.

If you take the count of each of these windows, you'll get a series of counts of 5 minutes of events, one second apart. It would look something like this:

```
source.windowWithTime(5 * 60000, 1000)   // create 5 minute windows, one second apart
      .flatMap(window => window.count()) // take each window and get the count once it completes (after 5 minutes)
      .subscribe(count => console.log(count));
```

I've used this to do exactly what you say - get a rate of events over a window of time in a non-stop stream of events. By having the windows overlap, you're generating a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) of the activity on the stream.